# How to use Firebase on Cortex-M embedded system

Tags: c, embedded, firebase

I'm just starting a new project, a thermostat connected to wifi and controlled anywhere from mobile phone. I've seen the Nest Thermostat which has a Cortex-A8 but I need to make a simpler and cheaper one, just a Cortex-M3 + wifi + temperature sensor, no screen.

The Android app (developed by other people) uses Firebase, so my embedded system should use it. 
I've selected a tiny RTOS, CyaSSL and lwIP, but this is my first Internet project and I need help with Firebase and everything related to Internet.

Is a Cortex-M3 suitable to connect to Firebase?
Is the selected software suitable to connect to Firebase?
What software do I need besides the selected? (Firebase API REST, JSON parser... and any software I don't even imagine)

I haven't found almost any info about such a system, there are some questions but most of them have no answer.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, to use the REST API you just need to implement the HTTP protocol, there is many RTOS that have full HTTP and HTTPS implementation.

I never used, but I know that mbed (http://mbed.org/) is designed for IOT,it is free, and developed by Arm, so it is probably the best way to go.

Just look for a C/C++ JSON Parser lib if it is not ready, otherwise you should develop one for yourself, it looks pretty simple.

Comment: Thank you Jonatan, I already had had a look to ARM mbed and I think it will be the best IoT software in the near future but today it is in alpha phase but my time to market must be very short. Here is a JSON parser, I'll try it: bitbucket.org/zserge/jsmn

Comment: So, what is your question? It looks you already have everything to get the job done.

Comment: Is a Cortex-M3 suitable to connect to Firebase (using TLS)?, What software do I need besides the selected?, any software I don't even imagine. Maybe somebody has done it before, maybe there is a C library to connect to Firebase, maybe ... any help will be appreciated

Comment: Why it would not be suitable? Just put the pieces together and see what happens, you do not have a development kit?

Comment: Maybe TLS requires more processing power, 8 bit microcrontrollers are not suitable for TLS, Cortex-A8 is suitable, Cortex-M3 is in the middle. I'll buy some demo boards but firtly I need to make an hex file to flash to uC.